# Filtering unknown character for OneDrive upload

Tags: powershell, onedrive

Currently using a small powershell script to check for illegal characters in a file structure, but I've come across a character I'm not familiar with. I need to modify the code to detect and replace whatever this character is (or represents) but I cannot physically type the character, it only displays when viewing in the file explorer. The character appears as a square bullet point, but will change to a box with a question mark if I copy/paste it anywhere. Anyone know the alt code for this character? Or an alternative line I can use to detect and replace it?

code it needs to go into is below:

```
function OneDrive-Check($Folder,[switch]$Fix){
    $Items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse

    $UnsupportedChars = '[!&{}~#%]'

    foreach ($item in $items){
        filter Matches($UnsupportedChars){
        $item.Name | Select-String -AllMatches $UnsupportedChars |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values
        }

        $newFileName = $item.Name
        Matches $UnsupportedChars | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "$($item.FullName) has the illegal character $($_.Value)" -ForegroundColor Red
            if ($_.Value -match "&") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "&", "and") }
            if ($_.Value -match "{") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "{", "(") }
            if ($_.Value -match "}") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "}", ")") }
            if ($_.Value -match "~") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "~", "-") }
            if ($_.Value -match "#") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "#", "") }
            if ($_.Value -match "%") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "%", "") }
            if ($_.Value -match "!") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace "!", "") }
         }
         if (($newFileName -ne $item.Name) -and ($Fix)){
            Rename-Item -LiteralPath $item.FullName -NewName ($newFileName)
            Write-Host "$($item.Name) has been changed to $newFileName" -ForegroundColor Green
         }
    }
}
```

Image of the character is below, on either side of the date:

[Unknown Illegal Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtRBo.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try to change your code page ? windows command line: chcp

Comment: @f14284 tip for the code page led me down the right path, got it solved now, thanks!

Comment: Well, You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to match the illegal characters as as `[string]`, I would try to identify the illegal character as a unicode character-code.

For that sample first your filename something like:

```
$name = $item.FullName
$name[0..$name.Length] | % {
    "$_ = \u$(([int64]$_).ToString('X4'))"
}
```

So you would get the actual unicode charcodes:

```
a = \u0061
k = \u006B
o = \u006F
s = \u0073
...
```

And then filter/replace the results then based on the unicode char-codes specified as `\u0000` as the hex code of the unicode character, something like:

```
$String -replace '\u005A\u0061\u007A', ''
```

Here you can find some great examples on actual unicode replaces:

- http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2015/08/powershell-remove-special-characters.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing the system Code Page may save you from programming a filter function. Try 'chcp' windows command line with the good code page.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp